# Error con estructura de datos C++: [Error] request for member 'Titulo' in 'libro', which is of non-class type 'Libro** {aka Libros**}'

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Buen dia.
Estoy intentando hacer una libreria en c++ con memoria dinamica ***MALLOC y FREE*** y con funciones.

Lo estoy haciendo en C++ con DevC++.
Cuando compillo me da el siguiente error:

`[Error] request for member 'Titulo' in 'libro', which is of non-class type 'Libro** {aka Libros**}'`

Intente poner variables para poder asignar los valores pero me marca otro error, a ese no le tome mucha importancia ppor tiene que ser con punteros, como lo estoy haciendo a continuacion.
Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
//librerias
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Declaramos la estructura Libros
typedef struct Libros{
    char Titulo[50];
    char Autor[50];
    int Codigo;
    float Precio;
    int num;
    struct Libros *Sig;//Puntero Siguiente para recorrer la lista enlazada
}Libro;//Libro es el tipo de dato para declarar la estructura

typedef Libro *LP; //Puntero al tipo de datdo Libro para no utilizar punteros de punteros

//declaramos las funciones
void InsertarLibros(LP *libro,int num);
void ImprimirLibros(LP *libro);
void EliminarLibros(LP *libro);

int main(){
    int num;
    LP libro; //Indica la cabeza de la lista enlazada, si la perdemos no podremos acceder a la lista
    libro = NULL; //Se inicializa la libro como NULL   ya que no hay ningun libro en la lista

    printf("\n\n\t\t\t***LIBRERIA***\n");
    printf("\n\t\t 1 -> Ingresar Nuevo Libro.");
    printf("\n\t\t 2 -> Mostrar Libros y Salir");
    printf("\n\t\t Opcion: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    while(num!=2){
        printf("\n\n\t\tTitulo: ");
        scanf("%s",libro->Titulo);
        printf("\n\t\tAutor: ");
        scanf("%s",libro->Autor);
        printf("\n\t\Codigo: ");
        scanf("%d",libro->Codigo);
        printf("\n\t\tPrecio: ");
        scanf("%f",libro->Precio);
        InsertarLibros(&libro,num);
        printf("\n\n\t\t 1 -> Ingresar Nuevo Libro.");
        printf("\n\t\t 2 -> Mostrar Libros y Salir");
        printf("\n\t\t Opcion: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
    }

    printf("\n\n\t\t\t***LIBROS INGRESADOS\n");
    ImprimirLibros(&libro);
    EliminarLibros(&libro);
    return 0;
}


void InsertarLibros(LP *libro, int num){
    LP nuevo; //Creamos un nuevo nodo
    nuevo = (Libro*) malloc(1000 *sizeof(Libro));//seteamos la memoria malloc con tipo de structura Libro
    //Asignamos los valores a un nuevo libro
    nuevo->Titulo = *libro.Titulo;
    nuevo->Autor = *libro.Autor;
    nuevo->Codigo = *libro.Codigo;
    nuevo->Precio = *libro.Precio;
    nuevo->num = num;
    nuevo->    Sig = *libro;
    *libro = nuevo; //libro pasa a ser el primero en la lista
}

void ImprimirLibros(LP libro){
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t***LIBROS INGRESADOS***\n");
    while(libro != NULL){//Mientras libro sea diferente de NULL
        printf("\n\t\tTitulo: %s",libro->Titulo);
        printf("\n\t\tAutor: %s",libro->Autor);
        printf("\n\t\tCodigo: %d",libro->Codigo);
        printf("\n\t\tPrecio: $ %.2f",libro->Precio);
    }
}

void EliminarLibros(LP *libro){
    LP actual; //Puntero auxiliar para elimanar correctamnte la lista

    while(*libro != NULL){//Mientras libro  no sea NULL
        actual = *libro;//Actual toma el valor de libro
        *libro = (*libro)->Sig;//Libro avanza 1 posicionen la lista
        free(actual);//se libera la memoria de la posicion actual(el primer libro), y libro queda apuntando al que ahora es el primero
    }
}
```

Me marca el error en la funcion incertar, cuando a asigno valores a el nuevo libro.
ya cambie los `.`por `->` y marca este error:

`[Error] request for member 'Titulo' in '* libro', which is of pointer type 'LP {aka Libros*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)`

Pongo 2 imagenes de los diferentes errores:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿ Para que haces `nuevo = (Libro*) malloc( 1000 * sizeof( Libro ) );` ? Con eso estás reservando memoria para **1000** libros O_o

Answer (score 0):

Tienes

```
typedef Libro *LP;
```

por lo que `LP *` es un **doble puntero**.

Y, para acceder a *cosas* a través de un doble puntero, has de hacer

```
void InsertarLibros( LP *libro, int num ) {
    LP nuevo; //Creamos un nuevo nodo
    nuevo = (Libro*) malloc(1000 *sizeof(Libro));

    nuevo->Titulo = ( **libro ).Titulo;
    nuevo->Autor = ( **libro ).Autor;
    nuevo->Codigo = ( **libro ).Codigo;
    nuevo->Precio = ( **libro ).Precio;
    nuevo->num = num;
    nuevo->Sig = *libro;
    *libro = nuevo;
}
```

Comment: me arroja el siguiente error: ```[Error] invalid array assignment```en dos lineas : ```nuevo->Titulo = (**libro).Titulo;``` ```nuevo->Autor = (**libro).Autor;```

Answer (score 0):

ya encontre una solucion:

```
 void InsertarLibros(LP *libro, int num){
LP nuevo; //Creamos un nuevo nodo
nuevo = (Libro*) malloc(1000 *sizeof(Libro));//seteamos la memoria malloc con tipo de structura Libro
//Asignamoslos valores a un nuevo libro
nuevo->Titulo[50] = (**libro).Titulo[50];
nuevo->Autor[50] = (**libro).Autor[50];
nuevo->Codigo = (**libro).Codigo;
nuevo->Precio = (**libro).Precio;
nuevo->num = num;
nuevo-> Sig = *libro;
*libro = nuevo; //libro pasa a ser el primero en la lista
```

}

asi si me compilo.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda...